# Error al intentar iniciar entorno virtual de Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cmd, powershell

me encuentro ante un problema al intentar ejecutar el archivo "activate.bat", desde la terminal de visual Studio, para activar mi entorno virtual en windows 10.

El error al posicionarme en la carpeta es el siguiente:

```
activate.bat : El término 'activate.bat' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe 
que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ activate.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (activate.bat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Suggestion [3,General]: No se encontró el comando activate.bat, pero existe en la ubicación actual. Windows PowerShell no carga comandos de la ubicación actual de forma predeterminada. Si confía en este comando, escriba ".\activate.bat". Vea "get-help about_Command_Precedence" para obtener información más detallada.
```

Ya he probado activando la ejecución de Scripts desde powershell.
Ya he probado ejecutando los otros scripts que ofrece el entorno para activarse ("Activate.ps1" y "activate")

Solo he podido activar el entorno virtual ejecutando el "activate.bat" desde el CMD

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda para ejecutar el .bat desde visual studio.

Comment: prueba con `.\activate.bat`

Comment: La terminal en Visual Studio esta usando powershell, para activar el entorno virtual tienes que hacerlo con `.\Activate.ps1`. Nota que tiene que empezar con `.\` ya que powershell por default  no ejecuta los archivos en la ubicación actual (Como te menciona el mensaje de error).

Comment: Yo desde el cmd tengo el mismo problema. Se que es algo sobre las politicas de ejecuciones de windows pero no se como arreglarlo. Siempre activo el entorno vircual desde el bash de git con el "source ruta/del/env/activate"

Comment: te recomiendo este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoRS763Uho8

Comment: tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione con .\activate.bat